# Android Studio app closes immediately after clicking convert

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-studio

I have this code made from Android Studio (Giraffe versio) where it simply a measurement calculator. This is a very basic program that was given to us as an assignment and we must create the program using what was taught to us in class. This is my attempt on this problem:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val etInchesToCentimeters = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etInchesToCentimeters)
    val etCentimeterToInches = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etCentimetersToInches)
    val etMilesToKilometers = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etKilometersToMiles)
    val etKilometersToMiles = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etMilesToKilometers)


    val tvInchesToCentimeters = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvInchesToCentimeterResult)
    val tvCentimetersToInches = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvCentimetersToInchesResult)
    val tvKilometersToMiles = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvKilometersToMilesResult)
    val tvMilesToKilometers = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvMilesToKilometersResult)

    val btnInchesToCentimeters = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnInchestoCentimeters)
    val btnCentimetersToInches = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnCetimetersToInches)
    val btnKilometersToMiles = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnKilometersToMiles)
    val btnMilesToKilometers = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnMilesToKilometers)

    var inchesToCentimeterResult: Double
    var centimeterToInchesResult: Double
    var kilometersToMilesResult: Double
    var milesToKilometersResult: Double



    btnInchesToCentimeters.setOnClickListener(){
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Converted Inches To Centimeters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        var inches = etInchesToCentimeters.text.toString().toDouble()
        inchesToCentimeterResult = inches * 2.54
        tvInchesToCentimeters.text =inchesToCentimeterResult.toString()

    }
        btnCentimetersToInches.setOnClickListener(){
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Converted Centimeters To Inches", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            var Centimeter = etCentimeterToInches.text.toString().toDouble()
            centimeterToInchesResult = Centimeter * 0.393701
            tvCentimetersToInches.text =centimeterToInchesResult.toString()

        }

        btnKilometersToMiles.setOnClickListener() {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Converted Kilometers To Miles", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            var Kilometer = etKilometersToMiles.text.toString().toDouble()
            kilometersToMilesResult = Kilometer * 0.621371
            tvKilometersToMiles.text = kilometersToMilesResult.toString()
        }

        btnMilesToKilometers.setOnClickListener() {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Converted Miles To Kilometers", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            var Mile = etMilesToKilometers.text.toString().toDouble()
            milesToKilometersResult = Mile * 1.609344
            tvMilesToKilometers.text = milesToKilometersResult.toString()
        }
}
}
```

The problem is that, the conversion of Centimeters to Inches, and Inches to Centimeter works normally it converts how I intended it to be, but when it comes to Kilometers to Miles and Miles to Kilometers, the app suddenly crashes and close. I already double checked each Widgets ID name hoping that the issue would be on my naming not matching from my .kt to the names I used in my .xml but the issue is still the same, I also tried rewriting it but to no avail. is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Check the Logcat on what exception is thrown.

Comment: @Imaginewagons Please also add your stack trace from logcat.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is issue in these lines

```
val etMilesToKilometers = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etKilometersToMiles)
val etKilometersToMiles = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etMilesToKilometers)
```

You might want to write

```
val etMilesToKilometers = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etMilesToKilometers)
val etKilometersToMiles = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etKilometersToMiles)
```

thats why `etMilesToKilometers` and `etMilesToKilometers` might be coming null, and app was crashing